# Swift: how to get the correct String size

Tags: ios, string, swift

I want to calculate the size of a string, to resize a UILabel. I used three different ways to calculate the size, to be exact, two ways. But I got three different results, and totally confused.
The most confusing thing is that I created a UILabel and use `sizeToFit()` to get the size. then I use the size to create a real UILabel and display it, but the label is truncated. Then I use `sizeToFit()` again to adjust the real UILabel, and the size is larger.

I doubted if it's caused by scale differences. But it is still three results on different simulators/devices.

Here's my code:

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let items = ["connected devices", "join session", "start host"]
    let font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(16)
    var i = 0
    for item in items {
        let size = item.size(font: font)
        print("\(size)")

        let attriSize = item.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:font])
        print("attriSize\(attriSize)")

        let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50 + i*50), size: size))
        label.text = item
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        label.sizeToFit()
        print("\(label.bounds.size)")

        view.addSubview(label)
        ++i
        print("\n")
    }
}
}
extension String {
func size(font font: UIFont) -> CGSize {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectZero)
    label.text = self
    label.font = font
    label.sizeToFit()
    let size = label.bounds.size

    return size
}

}
```

and the results are

(137.333333333333, 19.3333333333333)
attriSize(137.0859375, 19.09375)
(144.666666666667, 20.3333333333333)

(84.3333333333333, 19.3333333333333)
attriSize(84.265625, 19.09375)
(89.0, 20.3333333333333)

(70.0, 19.3333333333333)
attriSize(69.765625, 19.09375)
(73.6666666666667, 20.3333333333333)

I really want to know what's wrong with `sizeToFit()`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is working example that can help you :

```
let fixedWidth = textView.frame.size.width
    textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    let newSize = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: fixedWidth, height: CGFloat.max))
    var newFrame = textView.frame
    newFrame.size = CGSize(width: max(newSize.width, fixedWidth), height: newSize.height)
    textView.frame = newFrame;
```